# can not identify input element with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

source code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="btnclock1" type="button" class="btn btn-metis-2 btn-lg btn-round" style="font-size: 20px;background-color: #FF8001;border-color: #FF6000; margin: 10px;" value="　簽到　"onclick="ClickClock('0001');" />
```

I try to use python to click this button , but with error : no such element: Unable to locate element

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='btnclock1']").click()
#driver.find_element_by_id("btnclock1").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='　簽到　']").click()
```

Comment: Have you tried the explicit wait to make sure the element is present before clicking on it. If that does not work, then I suspect the element may be present in the iframe.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. Make sure that the weblement is loaded on the webpage before you click on it. Since the tag name is "<input>" I don't think it is a button it has to be an textbox.